# Modifying Keras LSTM Loss Function

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I am working on a sequence to sequence learning task. My LSTM network currently marks each correct time step in the sequence correctly predicted as a correct instance while calculating accuracy. 
For example...
If I was learning the sequence 
1 3 5 7 9 -》2 4 6 8 10
Then my network considers 1 -》 2 as a correct instance then 3-》4 as a correct instance. 
However I want to modify this so that each sequence predicted entirely without any error would be considered as a correct instance. 
The code for my model is given

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, SimpleRNN
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
import os 

HIDDEN_DIM = 250
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True), input_shape = (17, 129)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])
```